# Struts LabelValueBean Iteration takes time

Tags: java, loops, foreach, struts, java-6

I have a loop that iterates 28000 times, when i deploy it to server, it takes around 1.5 minutes to execute. When i am running it locally on my machine, it only takes 2 seconds. I tried everything but it is still taking time.

```
dt =(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date()));
out.println(dt);
int intSize = dropDown3.size();
for (int intCtr = 1; intCtr < intSize; intCtr++)
{
    lbValueBean = ((LabelValueBean) dropDown3.get(intCtr));
    if (intCtr == intSize - 1)
    {
        strVal1 = strVal1 + lbValueBean.getLabel();
    } else
    {
        strVal1 = strVal1 + "" + lbValueBean.getLabel() + ",";
    }
}
String data= stringParse(strVal1.toString());

out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date()));
```

My Server has over 16GB of RAM and has enough processing power but still this loop takes time.

Comment: Do you really have 28,000 items in a drop down?  Just because it runs fast locally does not mean you will get the same performance in production.

Comment: Yes, i have 28000 items in an autocomplete box

Comment: You should measure what exactly takes time in this code. Are `lvValueBean.getLabel` calls expensive? How much time is spent in a loop and how much in `stringParse`?

Comment: I did some analysis and found that lbValueBean = ((LabelValueBean) dropDown3.get(intCtr)); is taking most of the time. But i am really curious to know why does it takes too much time on Server

Comment: Personally I'd recommend doing this in a very different way, like Ajax. But giant string concatenations will never be great--at the very least you should explicitly use a `StringBuilder` or `StringJoiner` and see how that helps.

Comment: Remove `LabelValueBean` and problem might disappear.